# Installing a visual studio windows forms application on a pc that doesn't have .net framework installed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project

i have a C#.net windows forms application that i need to deploy, can i in some way copy the .net framework dlls that i used in the project to the setup project so that i can avoid to download .net framework on the target machines.

Answer (score 2):

The .NET framework version that your application targets must be installed on the client system. This is something that is usually handled by the installer during setup. Most installation builders such as the integrated Setup project in Visual Studio, Inno Setup and Nullsoft Scriptable Install System will detect if all of your app prerequisites are installed during installation.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you need to install the .NET framework but there are technologies like [Spoon Studio](http://spoon.net/Studio/) that wrap your application in a container. In most cases I think you are better installing the .NET Framework on machine to avoid debugging issues with these types of tools. For Windows Forms apps you can install the [.NET Client Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx) which reduces the download size.